# Delete specific row in database table and generatet html table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, delete-row

This is my delete page :

```
<?php 
require('includes/config.php'); 

    $id = $_GET['ID'];
    $pdoConnect = new PDO($db);
    $query='DELETE * FROM studentraspored WHERE ID = "' . $id . '" ';
    $pdoResult = $db->prepare($query);

    $pdoExec = $pdoResult->execute($query);

    header('location:index.php');
?>
```

This is generated table in my “memberpage.php”:

```
if (count($rows)){
    foreach ($rows as $row) {       
        $_SESSION['row'] = $rows;
        $id = floatval($row['ID']);
        echo "<tr>" .
            '<form action="delete_raspored.php" method="post">'.
            "<td>" . $row["ID"] . "</td>" .
            "<td>" . $row["den"] . "</td>" .
            "<td>" . $row["chas"] . "</td>" .
            "<td>" . $row["predmet"] . "</td>" .
            "<td>" . $row["profesor"] . "</td>" .               
            "<td>" . $row["prostorija"] . "</td>" .
            "<td>" . $row["tip"] . "</td>" .
            '<td><input type="submit" id="' . $id . '" value="Delete" ></td>'.
            "</form>".
            "</tr>"
```

This not working properly. I don't understand why maybe something i missed with `floatval`

Comment: Maybe.  You should be using an integer for your ID, rather than a float.  You may not be getting a 1/1 match when your run your query.

Comment: Hmm might have to update answer, what is `$db` and where is it defined?

Comment: @chris85 `$db` is database conn defined in config.php

Comment: Okay, that's what I though, so you don't need `$pdoConnect = new PDO($db);`, I'll update answer.

Comment: @ValentinGjorgoski Does the answer below work?

Comment: @chris85 No, i don't know what else to do. I fixed it code as you say.

Comment: Is error reporting on, is anything in the logs? What is the URL of the page when you load it?

Comment: @chris85 no error reporting url is still the same, it also refresh the page, but not delete row

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102398/discussion-between-chris85-and-valentin-gjorgoski).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by trying this:

```
<?php 
require('includes/config.php'); 
$id = $_GET['ID'];
$query='DELETE FROM studentraspored WHERE ID = ?';
$pdoResult = $db->prepare($query);
$pdoResult->execute(array($id));
header('location:index.php');
exit();
```

Note the placeholder in place of the actual value, this will prevent SQL injections. The value is passed in in the execute, or you could bind it (http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php). http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

The `delete` syntax was also off, `delete` deletes a whole row not specific columns, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html.

In your `form` I also don't see an element named `ID` so that could be another issue and your form is submitting via `POST`, not `GET`.